# Set up cross-domain measurement for multiple domains IN GA4

Tags: tracking, click-tracking

I am following the devguide per google on how to setup cross domain tracking.

I am good with the code, however not clear if one have to track multiple cross domains, will the linker code be same on all domains or just the domain which needs to be tracked?

Specifically,

```
​gtag('set', 'linker', {
  'domains': ['example.com', 'example-b.com', 'example-c.com']
});
```

If I have to track three domains, so will the above code(including the rest of the part) needs to go on all the domains?

Or if we can put the following code for tracking example.com only

```
​gtag('set', 'linker', {  
    'domains': ['example.com']
});
```

following code for example-b.com only

```
​gtag('set', 'linker', {
  'domains': ['example-b.com']
});
```

following code for example-c.com only?

```
​gtag('set', 'linker', {
  'domains': [ 'example-c.com']
});
```